# CakePHP View cache by a batch (cron) program

Tags: caching, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm developing a application by using CakePHP 1.3.7

The application has billing reportpage for each users.

some users make big billing report 
so the pages reponse delayed for the users.

I'd like to create cache files for the heavy users.

What is the best solution for creating view chache(report) for each heavy users?